# Transfer site to shared hosting server

Tags: zend-framework, web-hosting

is it possible (if not then whats the easiest way to) transfer a site created on a local server using zend framework to a hosted server by an isp.  Is it even possible to create a site using the zend framework on an isp's server.

Comment: you need to provide more information about the destination host and your existing configuration.

Comment: Depends on how your server is configured. E.g. if no PHP is available then it won't work. Best method to transfer the data is probably [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp) ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is a very simple task to do - normally paths, database links and a few bits and pieces need to be customised - but not too much work.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Yea, your main objective is to transfer all files to the server and database into your DB Server, Edit your configuration to change the paths to the the new servers relative paths.

Any other issues that may arise should not be difficult to over come.

Comment: Correct - I would be willing to help you achive this if you are having problems